# Popups in R Studio

Tags: rstudio

Does anybody know how to enable/disable these code suggestions in R Studio?

[image: Image Here]

Comment: Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Completion. That should be enabled by default though.

Comment: @nrussell, post as answer please?

Answer (score 7):

1. First, go to tools in that click on global options.
2. You will find code option on the left side and click on it then click on completion.
3. You will find **Show help tooltip after function completions** .check or uncheck to enable/disable code suggestions.
4. Please find the below picture.

[image]